# Unity: RegisterType with the same namespace but from different assemblies

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have code that register two classes with the same names and namespaces but from different assemblies.  Here's how I resolve this problem using Unity config file:

```
  <register type="IMyService" mapTo="CoordinatingMyService" />
  <register type="IMyService" mapTo="MyNamespace.MyService, MyService.Version1" name="V1"/>
  <register type="IMyService" mapTo="MyNamespace.MyService, MyService.Version2" name="V2"/>
```

My question is how I can achieve the same in code instead of the config file.

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong? Do you have compile-time access to these types? (Extern aliases may help...)

Comment: @JonSkeet It works fine with the config file.  I just want to have the same behavior by registering the types in code instead of using the config file.

Comment: You should look at this post, you may find the answer you're looking for : [http://csharp.2000things.com/2012/03/05/532-using-identically-named-types-from-different-assemblies/]

Comment: @krimog Thanks for the link but I don't think it's going to help me in this case.  BTW you link has ']' at the end.  And when you click on it you get 404.  Modify the link by removing ']' at the end.